# Need to type exec bash everytime at startup

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm sure this is a fairly simple problem, but I've put together a .bashrc file (located in my home directory) It includes my PS settings, some environmental exports and some aliases. First, I've read that these aren't all supposed to go into a .bashrc file but instead to include some of it in .bash_profile
If I include a .bash_profile file then none of the changes make any effect. If I keep everything as one long .bashrc file then everything works as planned....once "exec bash" is entered at the command line. Every time I start my unix environment however, I have to type "exec bash" in order for everything to work. Am I just missing something really simple here? Sorry if this has been answered, a search didn't really bring up anything useful (could be my poor search!)

Comment: What are the bash and linux versions?

Answer (score 2):

According to [[Man7]: chsh(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chsh.1.html) (or `man chsh`), you should run:

```bash
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Note: On some *Nix* distributions, location might be: ***/usr**/bin/bash*.

Comment: The strange part is, without having to use chsh if I enter "echo $SHELL" in the terminal "/bin/bash" is returned

Comment: `getent passwd $USER` will tell your what your login shell is. If it's already `/bin/bash`, the `chsh` won't make any difference.

Comment: What does `echo $BASH` or `export` print out (before running `exec bash`)? Here is [an external link](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html) or [a more detailed one from superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/789448/choosing-between-bashrc-profile-bash-profile-etc) that states differences between different bash config files.

Comment: echo $BASH gets me /bin/bash as well